# How can I extend a table with backend data by columns instead of rows in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

I have a table layout that currently looks like this:

This works well because I can place all my data for one row inside of my `item` object, and just render the `TableRow` object as `<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td>...`.

One solution could be to subdivide my `item` object by column, and return only the corresponding value:

```
  <tbody>

    <tr v-for="(item, rowIndex) in store.selectedItems" :key="item.id">
      <!-- iterate over each column within each row -->
      <td v-for="(col, colIndex) in columns" :key="colIndex">
        {{ item[col.field] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

However, ideally I would like to define the whole column in a single `TableCol` component instead of having to render the entire table like this. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to create a separate shared component for `column`, So that you can reuse that anywhere by just passing a dynamic props. If Yes, Here you go **:**

```js
Vue.component('tableCol', {
  props: ['column', 'rowitem'],
  template: `<td>{{ rowitem[column.field] }}</td>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    store: {
      selectedItems: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Alpha',
        age: 21
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Beta',
        age: 25
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Gamma',
        age: 30
      }]
    },
    columns: [{
      field: 'name'
    }, {
      field: 'age'
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in store.selectedItems" :key="item.id">
        <template>
          <table-col v-for="(column, index) in columns" :column="column" :rowitem="item" :key="index"/>
        </template>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```